# geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, homebrew

При попытке запуска селениум скрипта, как всегда идет ругань насчет PATH и geckodriver

`Geckodriver executable needs to be in PATH`

Попытался установить через `brew install geckodriver`

И получил вот такое

```
schedude@cs193956:~$ brew install geckodriver
Error: No available formula with the name "homebrew/dupes/unzip" (dependency of geckodriver)
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Использую Ubuntu 16.04

**UPD**

Скачал tar исходник с их репозитория на гитхаб, распаковал и положил по такому пути:

```
 /home/schedude/geckodriver
```

Указываю точный путь

```
firefox_path=('/home/schedude/geckodriver')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_path)
```

Получаю ошибку

```
[Errno 20] Not a directory: '/home/schedude/geckodriver'
```

Comment: связанный вопрос [How to install geckodriver in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/870530/3712)

Comment: про brew и про "not a directory" отдельно лучше спросить (brew не стандартный менеджер пакетов на Ubuntu)

Comment: firefox_path должен быть директорией, в которой хранится geckodriver `firefox_path='/home/schedude'`

Comment: @godva я сделал уже правильный путь, но он все равно не видит PATH(

Comment: `webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/home/schedude/geckodriver')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась благодаря использованию `executable_path`

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/home/schedude/webdriver/geckodriver')
```